# API Manager Upgrade 1.5 to 1.6

Tags: repository, wso2

Is it correct that the DB-scripts in $WSO2_AM_HOME/dbscripts, only contains migration scripts until version 1.5?

Can we assume that WSO2-AM 1.6 db-repository is the same as version 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the databases when migrating from APIM 1.5 ->1.6. You can find the migration scripts and the readme file from [1].
Seems,the relevant scripts has not been included to APIM 1.6.0 packs and created [2] to track this.

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.6.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.5.0_to_1.6.0/

[2] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1969

Thanks;

/Lalaji

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to increase the prio of bug, since this is essential for migration. It is not mentioned anywhere only your command that is pointing to a branche in  SVN.

Comment: I am using a 'clean' 1.5.0 database repository. But based on your anwser, there are errors in the Oracle.sql scripts:
1) the table am_workflows already exists
2) the syntax of am_workflows contains a syntax error 'AUTO_INCREMENT' does not work for oracle. Should be done via trigger. (as I have described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740479/wso2-am-type-mistake-in-oracle-sql-scripts)
3) the sequence am_wokflows_sequence already exists
4) the alter table script, contains already the new column.